# How to connect and get my form to submit in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I can create a user, then login using the user, then I can access to the form, once I finished the form and I submit it, I got the error.

I also can see that the user name and password are being stored in MongoDB.

I'm a beginner. How can I send the information to the server then generate a PDF, if is possible and store that information.

```
// index.js: This file is often the entry point of a Node.js application. It typically initializes your application, sets up any necessary configurations, defines routes (if it's a web server), and starts the server or performs other application-specific tasks.
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const collection = require("./config.js");
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const session = require('express-session');
const pdf = require('html-pdf');

const app = express();
const port = 8000;

// Middleware to parse JSON and urlencoded request bodies
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// Serve static files from the 'public' directory
app.use(express.static("public"));

// Use EJS as the view engine
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

// Middleware to handle sessions
app.use(session({
    secret: 'your_secret_key', // Change this to a random string
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));

// Render login page
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.render("login");
});

// Render signup page
app.get("/signup", (req, res) => {
    res.render("signup");
});

// Register User
app.post("/signup", async (req, res) => {
    const data = {
        name: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password
    };

    try {
        // Check if the username already exists in the database
        const existingUser = await collection.findOne({ name: data.name });
        if (existingUser) {
            return res.send('Este usuario ya existe. Porfavor trate con otro nombre de usuario.');
        }

        // Hash the password using bcrypt
        const saltRounds = 10;
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(data.password, saltRounds);

        // Replace the original password with the hashed one
        data.password = hashedPassword;

        // Create a new user document in the database
        const newUser = await collection.create(data);

        // Send a message indicating successful registration
        res.send('Registro exitoso. Ahora puedes iniciar sesión.');

        // Redirect the user to the login page after successful registration
        // res.redirect('/'); // Assuming '/' is the route for the login page
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error during user registration:', error);
        res.status(500).send('Error durante el registro. Por favor, inténtelo de nuevo más tarde.');
    }
});

// Login user 
app.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const check = await collection.findOne({ name: req.body.username });
        if (!check) {
            res.send("Nombre de usuario no puede ser encontrado.")
        }
        // Compare the hashed password from the database with the plaintext password
        const isPasswordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, check.password);
        if (!isPasswordMatch) {
            res.send("Contrasena NO valida");
        }
        else {
            // Set the user session
            req.session.user = check;
            res.redirect("/form"); // Redirect to form page after successful login
        }
    }
    catch {
        res.send("wrong Details");
    }
});

// Render user-specific form page after login
app.get("/form", async (req, res) => {
    // Check if the user is logged in
    if (!req.session.user) {
        return res.redirect("/"); // Redirect to login page if not logged in
    }
    res.render("form");
});

// Handle form submission
app.post("/submit-form", async (req, res) => {
    // Check if the user is logged in
    if (!req.session.user) {
        return res.redirect("/"); // Redirect to login page if not logged in
    }

    // Extract form data
    const formData = {
        userId: req.session.user._id, // Assuming user ID is stored in the session
        nombreCompleto: req.body.nombreCompleto,
        otroNombre: req.body.otroNombre,
        tipoVisa: req.body.tipoVisa,
        estadoCivil: req.body.estadoCivil,
        direccionCiudad: req.body.direccionCiudad,
        celular: req.body.celular,
        email: req.body.email,
        cambiosContacto: req.body.cambiosContacto,
        nacionalidad: req.body.nacionalidad,
        seguroSocialLicencia: req.body.seguroSocialLicencia,
        idiomas: req.body.idiomas,
        datosPadres: req.body.datosPadres,
        redesSociales: req.body.redesSociales,
        empleoActual: req.body.empleoActual,
        trabajoAnterior: req.body.trabajoAnterior,
        datosEstudio: req.body.datosEstudio,
        paisesVisitados: req.body.paisesVisitados,
        visaAnterior: req.body.visaAnterior, // Checkbox value, handle accordingly
        negacionVisa: req.body.negacionVisa, // Checkbox value, handle accordingly
        entradasSalidas: req.body.entradasSalidas,
        acompanante: req.body.acompanante,
        familiaresPais: req.body.familiaresPais,
        contactos: req.body.contactos,
        fechaViaje: req.body.fechaViaje,
        asesor: req.body.asesor,
        // Add more fields as needed
    };
    try {
        // Store form data in the database
        await collection.insertOne(formData);

        // Optionally, generate and save PDF
        const pdfContent = `<h1>Form Data</h1>
                            <p>Nombre Completo: ${formData.nombreCompleto}</p>
                            <p>Otro Nombre: ${formData.otroNombre}</p>
                            <p>Tipo de Visa: ${formData.tipoVisa}</p>`;
        // Add more fields as needed in the PDF content

        const pdfFilePath = path.join(__dirname, 'form_data.pdf');
        await generateAndSavePDF(pdfContent, pdfFilePath);

        res.send('Super ya casi cruzas el charco buey!');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error submitting form:', error);
        res.status(500).send('Error submitting form. Please try again later.');
    }
});

// Handle GET requests to /submit-form
app.get("/submit-form", (req, res) => {
    res.status(404).send("Not Found");
});

// Helper function to generate and save PDF
async function generateAndSavePDF(content, filePath) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        pdf.create(content).toFile(filePath, (err, res) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(res);
            }
        });
    });
}

// Start the server
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the error you are getting, in text format, as a code block? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you remove all the code you have provided?